# RabbitMQ message to multiple queues distribution equility

Tags: routes, rabbitmq, amqp

I'm using RabbitMQ to distribute messages from server to multiple clients. Each client has its own queue. There is one message published by the server to an exchange and there are multiple bindings which cause the distribution to multiple queues.

See the following diagram. A message is published to "Common Exchange" from which there are bindings to user specific exchanges (e.g. "User 1 Exchange") and finally there is last binding from user specific exchange to the user queue (e.g. "User 1 queue").
[image: Message routing]

Now my problem is that **I don't want some client to have an advantage of getting a message earlier than the others.** (e.g. User 1 will have the message available always earlier than User 2)

**My question is: Is the message available in the queues in deterministic order?**

**EDIT:** I know that the differences are likely very small (if any). Yet I need to know - clients are asking. 
The server produces quite a lot of large messages (thousands per second) during peaks. Also because of reliability we have HA policy on almost all queues which might also take some overhead. So I think if there are some differences during peaks they would eventually show up.

Thank you

Frank

Comment: Even if there was, the time difference would probably be unnoticeable.

Comment: Yes I know but for the clients even milliseconds are important (SLA says no client has the message first - how do I prove that? Is the routing technique really non-deterministic?)

Comment: "no client has the message first" is impossible. Even if you had one network cable per queue so you can send data simultaneously, the transit time will still vary. You prove it by measuring your system and showing that (on average) no client gets a message (some small time) before any others.

Comment: I'm sorry I wasn't precise... no client has the message *available* first. Yes, we can do and certainly will do the testing. But I'd rather have this information before the tests are done to avoid changing distribution model.

Comment: As I said, whether it is deterministic or not, you still probably won't notice the difference. And the only way to prove that is for you to test it.

Comment: Ok thank you for you help.

Comment: Why do you even have this common exchange? And even if you actually do have it, aren't there some queues missing to it? Or how do the messages go from common exchange to user exchanges?

Comment: That would be exchange to exchange binding

Comment: It is non deterministic. Each queue can be on a different server, with each server having different CPU/memory/network load, subtle differences in configuration, the list goes on. Messages may be evicted from memory on one server and not on the other so while both are available at the same time delivery will be slower on one server than the other. Even the way the clients consume messages can affect your server, for example client X uses a prefetch of 1 which causes more network traffic on server A than client Y with prefetch of 100 with its queue on server B.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I asked the very [same question on RabbitMQ forum](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/rabbitmq-users/MIPGqwi9mGs) and here's the answer:

> Message routing will first compile a list of exchanges for routing according to the bindings available,
>   then iterate over them. It works the same for queues.
>
> Then channel that performs routing will simply iterate over the queues and publish a message
>   to them. This happens asynchronously, so a message for the first queue on the list can reach
>   the queue earlier or later than, say, the last queue on the list.
>
> Consumer delivery with N queues also will happen asynchronously and (if enough cores are available
>   to the runtime) in parallel.

So to **answer the question**: there is **no predictable order** in which one particular **message is available on queues**.